# powershell condition not processing all values in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

I am newb in powershell but keen to put it into good use. I am working on a script which should do the following:

- Check for the existence of a specific folder in a specific location (mapped drive)
- If the folder exists, then return a listing
- If the folder does not exist, then create it.

Ideally, I would like to improve it in terms of check-if exists-remove-item (subdir); check-if not exists-create

This is to facilitate the automation of an archiving process for a specific piece of software. What I have right now sort of works but I cannot figure out how to make it do exactly what I want.

Here is the code:

```
$X = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")
$ChkFile = "f:\archive\$server\AABackup"
$myFolder = "f:\archive\$server"
$DirExists = Test-Path $ChkFile
Foreach ($server in $x){
  IF ($DirExists -eq $True) {
     Remove-Item $ChkFile -recurse
     import-Module "AppAssurePowerShellModule"
     start-archive -protectedserver $server -startdate "18/03/2013 5:30 PM" -path "f:\archive\$server"
    }
Elseif ($DirExists -ne $True) {
     New-Item -path $myFolder -itemType "directory"
     import-Module "AppAssurePowerShellModule"
     start-archive -protectedserver $server -startdate "18/03/2013 5:30 PM" -path "f:\archive\$server"
    }
}
```

Yes I know it is rough... It's my first attempt though so I could definitely benefit from the more experienced scripters here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the `$ChkFile` and `$myFolder` lines inside the foreach-loop. The variable `$server` is expanded to it's current value when you set the variables, so they are STATIC with the value of `$server` at the time of creation. By moving them into the foreach, they will be different for each server(like you want them to). Also, move the `Import-Module` line to the start of the script. When it's imported it's imported, you don't want or need to do that every time in your loop

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$ChkFile`, `$myFolder` and `$DirExists` *before* the loop, which means that  `$server` doesn't have a value yet, and -- since variables are evaluated immediately -- these variables will contain garbage.

You need to move those three statements inside the `foreach` loop.

You also don't need to compare `-eq $true`; this would be simpler:

```
if ($dirExists) {
    # ...
}
else {
    # ...
}
```

Oh, and you only need to import the module once -- do it at the top of the script.

Also, in terms of style: PowerShell keywords should generally be in lowercase: `foreach`, `if`, `elseif`; be consistent when invoking cmdlets (you have a mixture of `lower-case` and `Upper-Case` and `lower-Case`. Note that these don't make any real difference, but using a consistent style makes the code easier to read for someone else coming to it. I'm basing those rules on what I've seen on TechNet, PoshCode, and here, by the way -- they're definitely subjective.

And, personally, I use `$lowerCase` for local variables, and `$UpperCase` for parameters (because it makes the auto-generated help text look nicer).

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I have simplified the script significantly... The result is that the desired actions are taken against each server.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
$specificPath = Z:\MYDir\MySubDir

if(!(Test-Path $SpecificPath))
{
    Mkdir $SpecificPath  
}
Else
{
    Get-ChildItem $specificPath
}
```

Explanation: 
This checks for the existence of the path contained in `$SpecificPath` using Test-Path, which will return a Boolean value. 
Since I used the `(!())` syntax in my IF statement, it will try to evaluate the statement to false, IF the path DOES NOT EXIST, it will run the first block of code. 
`MkDir` is an alias for `New-ItemProperty`, if you pass just a path to `Mkdir` it will make a directory, similar to the windows MkDir command.
If the statement contained in the IF statement does not evaluate to false, the ELSE block will run, and execute a `get-childitem` on the `$specificpath` variable.